# Not showing tabs:

Tags: android

I'm new to android programing and need an advanced user to check my work.  For some reason when I run this app I get a blank screen instead of the two tabs that i want.  Thanks a lot!

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.storeitemfinder3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.layout.tab1);
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
        spec2.setContent(R.layout.tab2);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include layout="@layout/tab1" />

    <include layout="@layout/tab2" />

</TabHost>
```

**tab1.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/Avocados"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Avocados" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/Cashew_Nuts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cashew_Nuts"

        />
 ////android:checked="true"

</LinearLayout>
```

**tab2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.81"
        android:src="@drawable/tjs" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html):

> Container for a tabbed window view. This object holds two children: a
>   set of tab labels that the user clicks to select a specific tab, and a
>   FrameLayout object that displays the contents of that page. The
>   individual elements are typically controlled using this container
>   object, rather than setting values on the child elements themselves.

You need to have one `FrameLayout` as the child of the `TabHost`

Comment: There is a check button here on the answer (below the votes this question has). By clicking on it you set this answer as the one that answered your question. If this is the answer that solved your problem, do so. If not, select the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

May be due to this coz both having full screen so may be hiding Tabs just tried check the layout

**tab1.xml**

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

**tab2.xml**

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

So change it to this

**tab1.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/Avocados"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Avocados" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/Cashew_Nuts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cashew_Nuts"

        />
 ////android:checked="true"

</LinearLayout>
```

**tab2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.81"
        android:src="@drawable/tjs" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @user2749364 is that worked if worked then you should rate and accept